# Stop jquery function on it's running state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying some thing like this

[Demo JSFIDDEL](http://jsfiddle.net/c3755/)

the problem with this code is that it scrolles multiple time when i move the scroll bar up down..

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 50) {
        $('.mydiv2').show(1000);
    } else {
        $('.mydiv2').hide(1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't see the problem you're referring to!

Comment: The problem seems to be that it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/c3755/1/)

Check the link. You are hiding a div and showing it again with scroll event. You need to add `stop(true)` in hiding and showing also

```
if (y > 50) {
    $('.mydiv2').stop(true).show(1000);
} else {
    $('.mydiv2').stop(true).hide(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var y = $(this).scrollTop();
```

above statment makes multiple scroll because you scrolling up window using code